# How to add a cover page in book using tex

Tags: tex-core

I wanted to add a cover page before the title page. but it always create a blank page after the coverimage.
what is the proper code for adding a cover page without creating a blank page before title page.

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 left=5mm,
 right=5mm, 
 top=15mm,
 }
%\usepackage[paperheight=8in,paperwidth=5in,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=10mm,right=10mm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\footnotesize\arabic{page}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\footnotesize കടല്‍, എഴുത്ത്}
\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize അഭിജിത്ത് കെ എ}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{comment}
\geometry{
%total={170mm,257mm},
left=20mm,
right=20mm,
top=20mm,
bottom=20mm,
}
\end{comment}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.2} 
\definecolor{whitet}{RGB}{240, 240, 223}
\definecolor{whiteh}{RGB}{245, 237, 237}
\definecolor{whiten}{RGB}{239, 242, 233}
\definecolor{whitep}{RGB}{226, 240, 223}
\definecolor{whites}{RGB}{218, 230, 226}
\definecolor{gray2}{RGB}{140, 140, 140}
\definecolor{dgray}{RGB}{28, 28, 28}
\definecolor{vt}{RGB}{129, 0, 199}
\definecolor{yell1}{RGB}{194, 232, 79}
\definecolor{yell2}{RGB}{180, 186, 125}
\definecolor{bl1}{RGB}{148, 180, 235}
\definecolor{oldp}{RGB}{248,236,194}
\definecolor{pgco}{RGB}{248,249,243}
\definecolor{brt}{RGB}{69,55,47}

\setdefaultlanguage{malayalam}
\setmainfont[Script=Malayalam, HyphenChar="00AD]{Rachana}
\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{Times New Roman}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\fontspec[Color=red]{manjari}
\lefthyphenmin=3
\righthyphenmin=4
\linespread{1.2}
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom
\sloppy
\title{\textbf{\LARGE കടല്‍, എഴുത്ത്}}%\vspace*{-10mm}}
\author{\small{അഭിജിത്ത് കെ എ}}
\date{}
\color{brt}

%\CenterWallPaper{1}{sea-cover-tex.png}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{pgco}
 \includepdf[pages={1}]{cover.pdf}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There  exists a `coverpage` package.

Comment: It is helpful, if you provide a `MWE` of your code...

Comment: For a pdf, you pretty much need that blank page.

Comment: i have added my code in the question. please check it.

Comment: how does the coverpage package works?

Comment: why do we need that blank page in the pdf.

Comment: Place a real book in front of you on a desk and check it out.

Comment: oh now i get it. thank you